# How can you add parameters to attributes from localized .properties file in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How can I add dynamic values in localized `.properties` files?
I have a controller which uses `GlobalMessages` from hybris to add a message from `locales_**.properties`. The message should look like this:

```
**** [code] ****
```

Where `code` is a dynamic value.
I've tried to do something like:

```
model.addAttribute("code",codeValue);
```

Then set the message key:

```
code.display = **** ${code} ****
```

But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this in your jsp/tag file:

```
<spring:theme value="code.display" arguments="${code}" />
```

and change the message like this:

```
code.display = **** {0} ****
```

Also use one of the files in:

```
hybris/bin/custom/mystorefront/web/webroot/WEB-INF/messages/
```

Best idea is to use base.properties.